# Getting external from Assembler

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I have the following asm code that gets linked into my cpp project:

```
Some_Variable EQU 0x0F00F0F0
...
```

Now I would like to access Some_Variable from C code. I was not lucky with `extern uint32_t Some_Variable`. How do you exactly do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: That's not a variable; it's an _equate_, which is similar to a `#define` in C.

Comment: Yes sorry you are absolutely correct, still I'd like to access or get that value in C. Any idea?

Comment: You can't, equates don't actually exist, they're just macro's. Define it the same way in a C header and watch in horror as the values become different at some point in the future..

Comment: So the idea is to define a variable in asm and save the equate's content there and get that as an external from C?

Comment: What compiler do you use to compile you assembly project?

Comment: this MDK-ARM with the KEIL IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is indeed using variable that has constant value assigned to it. Not sure about your assembler but for nasm you can do the following:

```
Some_Variable equ 0x0F00F0F0

global _somevar
_somevar dd Some_Variable
```

And then in C:

```
extern int somevar
```

Most assemblers have similar keywords so I hope this helps.